# jquery ui tabs + grid object - ajax sends several queries

Tags: jquery, grid, var

i'm not so good at jquery and i've got this issue:

i'm using jquery tabs as:

```
<li><a href="content.php?div=Production">Production</a></li>
<li><a href="content.php?div=Digital">Digital</a></li>
```

declared as:

```
$(function() {

    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        load: function(event, ui) {
            console.log("load event ran");
            $('a', ui.panel).live("click", function() {
                   $(ui.panel).load(this.href);
                   return false;
                   });
        }
   });
   $("#tabs").bind('tabsshow',function(event, ui) {
    window.location = ui.tab;
})
});
```

in `content` i have grid definitions - each tab has **it's own** table to load:

```
switch($div){
            case "Production":
                $tab = '1';
                include('div_master.php');
                break;
            case "Digital":
                $tab = '2';
                include('div_digital.php');
                break;
            default:
                include('div_master.php');
                break;
        }
```

after above php i've got [grid](http://square-bracket.com/openjs) object loading db results:

```
$(function() {
    var grid = $(".grid").loadGrid({ ....});
});
```

i also store grid object in a variable so i can access `sql query` so i can export it to excel by pressing a button on a page:

```
    $('#toexcel').live("click",function() {
        var sql = grid.data().sql;
        $.ajax({
            url: "toExcel.php",
            data: "sql="+encodeURIComponent(sql),
        });
        sql = '';
    });
});
```

my problem is that when i load fist tab from fresh, export some results to excel, then change to second tab - the button exports the same query from the first tab!
so obviously `var sql = grid.data().sql;` is not updated with the new data despite grid being reloaded.

first tab always works no matter how many times i change between tabs,
but second works only when page/DOM is completely reloaded.

how do i correct this?

---

**Edit 2** - i have separated grids for both tables - still having the same issue.

i really don't think that the problem is with reusing the grid object - **i think that the problem is with jquery UI** - tabs, specifically how the handle reloading DOM.

---

**ADDITION**

please see firebug console for requests:
see when freshly loaded - ajax only send 1 request to toExcel, but after switching a tab (div-m - 1st tab, div-d - 2nd tab) it sends 2 requests. and depending on the tab it cancels either 2nd query for fist tab, 1st query for second tab - that's why 1st tab always working!

[image]

Comment: You should provide more detail:
What exactly is `$(".grid")` matching?
Do you call `.loadGrid({ ....});` later in your code?
What exactly is `loadGrid()`doing?

Atm. it is pretty obvious, that `grid.data().sql` always contains the same value, because you only seem to set `grid` once (upon document ready).

Comment: i have added the entire content.php code

Comment: `because you only seem to set grid once` - but on fist tab query always changing, meaning grid gets called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:** <sup>code stripped to the bone! ;)</sup>

your code should be like this:

```
var sql = '';
$(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.tab.hash).find('table').loadGrid({
                loadComplete: function() {
                    sql = $(this).data().sql;
                }
            });
        }
    });
    $('#toexcel').live("click", function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "toExcel.php",
            data: "sql=" + encodeURIComponent(sql),
        });
    });
});
```

---

```
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#production">Production</a></li>
            <li><a href="#digital">Digital</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="production">
         <table class="production grid" action="content.php?div=Production"></table>
       </div>
        <div id="digital">
         <table class="digital grid" action="content.php?div=Digital"></table>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Explanation:

when using jquery-ui tabs, the `<a>` tag that act as `tab` is not fired ( jquery prevent it's click event, cause it is actually used as tab and not as link ), also your html-tabs code will not work as expected ( will not switch tabs ) cause the `<a>` tag `hash` ( `href="#something"` ) should match the `id` ( `id="something"` ) of it's respective container ( in this case div ), instead you have associated to each anchor a direct url-query ( `content.php?..` ) that, again, will never be fired and in this case will never switch any tab too.

so the simple solution is to let the `<a>` tag act as tab by putting back the `#` + `id` as in my example and hook the tabs `ui` event and procede from there.

Comment: yes! as i suspected before - this behaviour is caused by ui tabs. i understand your explanation, but the solution is not quite suitable. if i draw all my grid tables in index, then they all immediately visible to everyone (even if i set display to none) - which i don't want to happen, as i have access levels. plus not all my tabs will have grids, so how would i load content for them?

Comment: actually you guided me to the right direction! all i did is i took your idea of assigning value to sql on loadComplete - and it works now! thank you

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing some details here, but maybe its worth loading each tab into its own .grid? that way there is no way the data can be mistakenly loaded from another tab

Set each tab into its own grid with completely differing classes:

```
<table class="productionGrid grid" action="div-d.php" title="detailed info">
<table class="digitalGrid grid" action="div-d.php" title="detailed info">
```

Then .loadGrid() in the same, completely separate manner:

```
$(function() {
    var productionGrid = $(".productionGrid").loadGrid({ ....});
    var digitalGrid = $(".digitalGrid").loadGrid({ ....});
});
```

Then include an excel export button within each tab:

```
$('#productiontoexcel').live("click",function() {
    var productionsql = productionGrid.data().sql;
    $.ajax({
        url: "toExcel.php",
        data: "sql="+encodeURIComponent(productionsql),
    });
    productionsql = '';
});
```

...

```
$('#digitaltoexcel').live("click",function() {
    var digitalsql = digitalGrid.data().sql;
    $.ajax({
        url: "toExcel.php",
        data: "sql="+encodeURIComponent(digitalsql),
    });
    digitalsql = '';
});
```

Im sure the code could be nicer but start simple and make it work, then add complexity and functionality once its working.

UPDATED: added more specific details after the code was shown

Comment: the problem is that at the mo i only have 2 tabs - but there will be more, so i don't really like repeating same code everywhere

Comment: after splitting up both girds, having put js for each grid exclusively - i'm still having the same problem

Comment: Ive updated my example above; surely having it all separate it cannot still load the wrong sql?

Comment: @ Hank - surely if the answer was simple i wouldn't offer 100 points of my reputation =) but i will provide full html code. if you want grid code - please follow the link i provided.

Answer (score 0):

I could be missing something obvious but I don't see where you are updating digitalGrid.data().sql; to anything but the default.  Perhaps you want to use Success or Complete callback of ajax to reload the data.  That said, there might be some code left out or something inherent to the grid tool that handles this.

**Psuedo code:**

```
$.ajax({
        url: "toExcel.php",
        data: "sql="+encodeURIComponent(digitalsql),
success: function(data) {
    var grid = $(".grid").loadGrid({ data});
}
    });
```

Comment: you might be very right! i have to check... the only thing that confuses me is - in browsers console - i can see that 2 different queries are sent but the correct one is cancelled!

Comment: no, actually this didn't work.. then again i'm loading each grid separately, on separate scripts. so the var should change..

Comment: it would be interesting to see the generated html and the full js.  It seems to me that the events and listeners are wired up incorrectly but I can't tell from the details provided here.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see in OpenJS Grid, the plugin is returning an array of elements because you're binding it to ".grid".
In your code you have this two times, so you'll receive two elements.

Can you try if this will work:

```
// This has to return the productionGrid's data
var sql = $("[class*=productionGrid]").data().sql
// This has to return the digitalGrid's data
var sql = $("[class*=digitalGrid]").data().sql
```

Comment: yes, that's correct - because i have 2 different grids. even changing one of the sql variables to sql1 - didn't help.